# Format Floating Point Number in input tag using angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to format my `<input type="number" ng-model="volume">` so that it display float number with 2 decimal places using angular's directive. I tried this

```js
angular.module('app').directive('input', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function(val){
                ngModel = ngModel.toFixed(2)
            });
        }
    };
});
```

But it didn't work since my ngModel keeps returning `controller {}`. I don't know what to do here. I tried $scope with controller also with no result. Any suggestion ?

I just found the most likely answer : http://gsferreira.com/archive/2014/05/angularjs-smart-float-directive/ with the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gsferreira/SCr6X/
.

It will automatically format any number(integer included) to floating point number and user still able to type more than 2 precision number. It's not an ideal solution for me